# how i can change dataframe and remove duplicate cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataferame like this:

[image: DF before]

I want change it to this:

[image: DF after]

Comment: Please post a small reproducible sample of your data set so that others can use it to help you get your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have helped shared the result with this answer

```
#Mask the value with empty string when value for matches previous row
df['Model']=df['Model'].mask(df['Model'].eq(df['Model'].shift(1)),'' )
df
```

Comment: Seeing the screenshot above, I guess a simple groupby actually works enough, or a stack

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.groupby` with the `group_keys = True`.

```
df.groupby("Model", group_keys=True).apply(lambda x: x).drop('Model',axis=1)

                tip   segment    pd    gear
Model                                      
Mazda        0    3  Japanese  2020    auto
             1    2  Japanese  2016  manual
             2    3  Japanese  2020    auto
Toyota Camry 3  glx  Japanese  2019  manual
             4  gli  Japanese  2018  manual
```